# Not understanding the Layout of LunarLander sample game

Tags: android, xml, layout

In LunarLander sample game provided as android sample game, I have a confusion about the layout.

As far I know there are some default layouts like FrameLayout, RelativeLayout and so on.
But in the below given layout xml file (Copied from LunarLander ) in line 6 they used

```
<com.example.android.lunarlander.LunarView
```

Can any one please explain me about the line ? 
If this is this is a layout then how can I manually declare or use this kind of layout ?

Here's the full  xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.example.android.lunarlander.LunarView
  android:id="@+id/lunar"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:text="@string/lunar_layout_text_text"
      android:visibility="visible"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:textColor="#88ffffff"
      android:textSize="24sp"/>
 </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinarView is a custom view ( IIC, derived from surface view ). And as it packed into frame layout,   other silbing (RelativeLayout)    is overlay over surface view.    To use it  in your application it has to be available as class.  ( via jar,  or you can develop it itself )

Comment: Search the code for LunarView.  In addition Google up SurfaceView : it's explained in the Android docks.  A far better use of your time then posting here without doing any research whatsoever.